# Selecting from a subset based on a value inside the same subset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have created a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(RecordDate datetime, First VARCHAR(255), Last VARCHAR(255), Value int)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('2011-03-01 00:00:00.000','john','smith','10')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('2011-03-01 00:00:00.000','john','adams','60')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('2011-03-01 00:00:00.000','john','resig','90')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('2011-03-01 00:00:00.000','john','balte','95')

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('2011-03-01 01:00:00.000','john','smith','98')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('2011-03-01 01:00:00.000','john','adams','67')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('2011-03-01 01:00:00.000','john','resig','24')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('2011-03-01 01:00:00.000','john','balte','20')

SELECT * FROM #TEMP

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

which now contains the following records:

```
RecordDate              First   Last    Value
2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 john    smith   10
2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 john    adams   60
2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 john    resig   90
2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 john    balte   95
2011-03-01 01:00:00.000 john    smith   98
2011-03-01 01:00:00.000 john    adams   67
2011-03-01 01:00:00.000 john    resig   24
2011-03-01 01:00:00.000 john    balte   20
```

I am trying to obtain a table like the following:

```
RecordDate                first    Good     Bad
2011-03-01 00:00:00.000   john     3        1
2011-03-01 01:00:00.000   john     2        2
```

The way I am computing Good and Bad is by taking the `MAX` of all people with the first name `john` on the specific date and then applying it as a filter on the original dataset for that particular date and first name. Only values greater than `0.5*MAXValue` are considered `Good`.

In the result table, there are 3 good values because the maximum value for the first date was `95` and only `60,90,95` are greater than `0.5*95` so the result has `(Good,Bad) = (3,1)`. In the second result, likewise, it is `(2,2)`.

My table is sufficiently big and has close to 300 million records and I am not able to understand where to start to do this efficiently. Any suggestions on what an efficient way might look like?

My current (working but expensive) approach is give below:

```
SELECT    RecordDate
        , FirstName
        , 
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM #TEMP
            WHERE Value > 0.5*(SELECT MAX(Value) FROM #TEMP WHERE RecordDate = A.RecordDate AND FirstName = A.FirstName)
            AND RecordDate = A.RecordDate AND FirstName = A.FirstName
        ) AS Good
        ,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM #TEMP
            WHERE Value < 0.5*(SELECT MAX(Value) FROM #TEMP WHERE RecordDate = A.RecordDate AND FirstName = A.FirstName)
            AND RecordDate = A.RecordDate AND FirstName = A.FirstName
        ) AS Bad
FROM #TEMP A
GROUP BY RecordDate, FirstName;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
select 
   t.RecordDate,
   COUNT(case 
           when t.Value > MV.MaxValue * 0.5 then 1
           else null
         end) Good,
   COUNT(case 
           when t.Value <= MV.MaxValue * 0.5 then 1
           else null
         end) Bad
from #Temp t inner join
(select RecordDate, MAX(Value) MaxValue
 from #Temp Group By RecordDate) MV on t.RecordDate = MV.RecordDate
Group by t.RecordDate
```

The trick is creating a derived table with the max values for each record date and then `INNER JOIN` it with the table itself. Once you get the max values solved, you can access them directly.

**Update**

I see you updated your question and included the first name in the result. Never fear, here's the solution:

```
select 
   t.RecordDate,
   t.First,
   COUNT(case 
           when t.Value > MV.MaxValue * 0.5 then 1
           else null
         end) Good,
   COUNT(case 
           when t.Value <= MV.MaxValue * 0.5 then 1
           else null
         end) Bad
from #Temp t inner join
(select RecordDate, First, MAX(Value) MaxValue
 from #Temp Group By RecordDate, First) MV 
   on (t.RecordDate = MV.RecordDate and t.First = MV.First)
Group by t.RecordDate, t.First
```

Comment: Thank you for the trick. I needed the result to be grouped by the FirstName so I edited your answer to reflect this. Would you mind taking a look at it? If that's not right, I'll revert the changes.

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad you posted your answer before I completed mine; I was using `NTILE(2)` and your answer made me re-check what the question was asking. :) +1

Comment: Yes, I did :) Always glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

The nested queries that refer to the outer query may be causing a lot of repetitive work.
This will just calculate all the MAX for all names and dates in one go:

```
SELECT RecordDate, FirstName, MAX(Value) FROM #TEMP GROUP BY RecordDate, FirstName
```

Now join back to the original data:

```
SELECT A.RecordDate, A.FirstName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Value > MaxVal*0.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GOOD,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Value > MaxVal*0.5 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS BAD,
FROM #TEMP A INNER JOIN
     (SELECT RecordDate, FirstName, MAX(Value) as MaxVal 
      FROM #TEMP GROUP BY RecordDate, FirstName) B 
         ON (A.RecordDate = B.RecordDate AND A.FirstName = B.FirstName)
GROUP BY A.RecordDate, A.FirstName
```

Comment: Note this uses SUM(1 or 0) not COUNT(1 or NULL). Are you sure NULL doesn't add to a count ?

Comment: It happens :). Your solution differs by using `SUM`, but it also works. You should leave it as it might help future visitors.

Comment: Well, no. I'm working from memory without a server to test on.

Comment: Well, since OP posted the code to actually **create** the structure and the data, it was easy for me to actually run the queries. I can tell you the code I posted runs smoothly :) Also, theoretically speaking, COUNT is not supposed to count nulls